# After authorize facebook permissions facebook don't open

Tags: android, facebook

I follow the API facebook guide, here's the code:

```
ib2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

    list = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

             /*
             * Get existing access_token if any
             */
            mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
            long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
            if(access_token != null) {
                facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
            }
            if(expires != 0) {
                facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
            }

            /*
             * Only call authorize if the access_token has expired.
             */
            if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

                facebook.authorize(Answer.this, new String[] {"user_about_me","publish_checkins"}, new DialogListener() {
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();
                    }

                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

                    public void onError(DialogError e) {}

                    public void onCancel() {}
                });
            }
    }};


    ib2.setOnClickListener(list);
```

And

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Each one In the right position with the right declarations. And...

The first time doing Onclick on the button, facebook ask me to accept the permissions required for my app.

But...

The second time I do Onclick on the same button, facebook window don't open. Why can be that?

If I set the permissions I should see the authorization OK!!!

Answer (score 1):

do you have the official Facebook application installed? Because if you do, it's a bug I believe they still have not fixed.

I don't know if that's the problem, but you could try forcing the dialog: `facebook.authorize(Answer.this, new String[] {"user_about_me","publish_checkins"}, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new DialogListener() {`

I do not quite understand what you are experiencing here, so please let me know how it works.

Comment: I know SO policy is not to just post "thanks" but ... sorry policy "Thanks!". Not only do I not get any facebook window if the app is authorised on the FB side but just hasn't run on the Android side, but it also just .. quits without any chance to trap or do anything else. Very suboptimal if you ask me. So anyway, have made the modification as you recommended there and by jove it works a good 'un. Lastly .. where is the list of facebook SDK bugs ? I'm sure this won't be the last..

Comment: I'm glad to hear I could help someone out! I agree it's a very weird bug, and for all I know, this workaround probably isn't the most reliable, but it works for me. The complete list of bugs can be found here: developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Answer (score 0):

```
"The first time doing Onclick on the button, facebook ask me to accept the permissions     required for my app."
```

In this case, as it is the first time you login the app with Facebook, you app does not have the access token and expires

facebook.isSessionValid()=false

-->facebook.authorize()will run

Facebook will ask you for the permission(as your facebook accout never permit your app before)

But for the second time,

The access token and the expires have been saved to the sharepreference,
==>facebook.isSessionValid() is true,

==>facebook.authorize() will not run

==>seem as logged in

So facebook windows will not pop up.

If you want to see the facebook pop up window again,

1) clean your app's cache

2)terminate the app(access token in sharepreference will be clear)

Then you can see a facebook login window pop up, but you will not see the premission page,as you have permit your app already(only need to permit once)

If you want to see the facebook permission page again, just go to your Facebook, go to privacy setting-->Ads, Apps and Websites-->press edit setting and unauthorize your APP.
Then the Premission page will pop up again for your next login to the app